# Environment Variables, error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple

Tags: django, python-3.x, environment-variables, virtualenv

I'm setting up the enviroment variables in my venv created with virtualenv.
I created two scripts: postactivate and preactivate, The order of the commands that I follow are: **source venv/bin/activate**, **source venv/bin/postactivate** and **python manage.py runserver** but I have this error when I try to run my command  *python manage.py runserver* : **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple.**

Y tried some things: put the entire list in only one line, to exchange between single and double quotes, even, convert to a tuple.

postactivate script

```
export INSTALLED_APPS="[
                    'django.contrib.admin',
                    'django.contrib.auth',
                    'django.contrib.humanize',
                    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                    'django.contrib.sessions',
                    'django.contrib.messages',
                    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                    'rest_framework',
                    'rest_framework.authtoken',
                    'custom_user',
                    'corsheaders',
                    'django_s3_storage',
                    'django_ses',
                    'captcha',
                    'embed_video',
                    'bootstrap_forms',
                    'models_simple_trans',
                    'tables',
                    'markdown_filter',
                    'apps.countries',
                    'apps.companies',
                    'apps.organizations',
                    'apps.campaigns',
                    'apps.auctions',
                    'apps.users',
                    'apps.home',
                    'apps.emails',
                    'apps.adminpanel',
                    'apps.payments',
                    'helpers',
                    'celery',
                    'rest_framework_swagger',
                    'django_extensions',
                    'social_django',
                    'mapwidgets',
                    'rosetta',
                    'channels',
                    'django_user_agents',
                    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
                    'django_tables2', 
                  ]"
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you post your settings file as well? Looks like you are setting INSTALLED_APPS in the environment as a string. If you have a line like this in settings file: INSTALLED_APPS = os.environ.get('INSTALLED_APPS '), you might try chaning it to INSTALLED_APPS = json.loads(os.environ.get('INSTALLED_APPS '))

Comment: Yeah, that was my error, really I lost around 2 hours trying to find the problem, really thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are setting INSTALLED_APPS in the environment as a string. If you have a line like this in settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = os.environ.get('INSTALLED_APPS '),
```

you might try chaning it to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = json.loads(os.environ.get('INSTALLED_APPS '))
```